# What could cause different efffect using HttpUrlConnection on different computers?

Tags: java, http, matlab, httpurlconnection, put

I wrote a HTTP server to manage resources in a RESTful fashion, and some clients (.NET, VBA).

I needed to use the RESTful API from MATLAB so I wrote a Java Client using HttpUrlConnection.

I worked fine on computers that was using it, except for one user whose PUT requests were received as POST requests.

My JAVA code includes:

```
   HttpURLConnection  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();       
   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   conn.setDoInput(true);
   conn.setRequestMethod(Method);
```

I read that the setDoOutput(true) is supposed to set the HTTP Method to POST, but since I called setRequestMethod(Method) with Method = "PUT", and that it worked from most stations, and that it's the only way I found to send a PUT request with HttpURLConnection, I don't know what could be wrong.

Each matlab client run the same 1.6 java version.

I couldn't find what was going on so I switched to Apache HTTP libraries (and it works), but I wonder what was happening with HttpURLConnection.

Answer (score 1):

> I read that the setDoOutput(true) is supposed to set the HTTP Method to POST

Whoever told you this is wrong as [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput%28boolean%29) makes no mention of this:

> A URL connection can be used for input and/or output. Set the DoOutput flag to true if you intend to use the URL connection for output, false if not. The default is false.

As you surmised, you should use [the `setRequestMethod(method)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29) to set the request type. So then what is the value of your variable `Method`? Why don't you just use `setRequestMethod("PUT")`?

Comment: The code I pasted is used in a function that handles both PUT and POST requests, the method being specified via a string input argument of that function, which is named Method.
When a client is putting a resource, Method is set to "PUT". My logs confirm that, even when the problem occurs ( PUT requests received as POST requests).

Comment: And you are totally right about setDoOutput(true) not setting RequestMethod to POST. So, no influence.

Comment: Well it sounds like it's possible that a bug could exist in when `Method` has a value of `PUT` or `POST`. How do you know that the `PUT` request your log shows you sending is received on the server-side as a `POST`? Have you tried examining the actual HTTP messages sent over the wire, with something like tcpdump or Wireshark?

Comment: Server-side, there is a test on context.Request.HttpMethod (where context is a .NET HttpListenerContext). I'm going to look at what is sent over the wire